# How to show row as a column in MYSQL tempTable result

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Net, MYSQL web Application.
We have created stored procedure which will return table, But now we want to change structure of that procedure for display purpose.
So How to make Mysql stored Procedures's TempTable result in follwing format?
Rows convert into columns.

[image]

Phoenix Solution Output :

[image]

Comment: Are there any other columns in the temp table?

Comment: Yes i have given columns to TempTable.                CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable ( Current varchar(1000), One  varchar(1000), thirtyOne  varchar(1000), sixtyOne  varchar(1000), Ninety  varchar(1000)) TYPE=HEAP;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```sql
SELECT 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Agedreceivable='Current' THEN AgedreceivableAmt END) Current,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Agedreceivable='1-30' THEN AgedreceivableAmt END) '1-30',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Agedreceivable='31-60' THEN AgedreceivableAmt END) '31-60',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Agedreceivable='61-90' THEN AgedreceivableAmt END) '61-90',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Agedreceivable='>90' THEN AgedreceivableAmt END) '>90'
  FROM
(
  SELECT @n := @n + 1 rownum, agedreceivable, agedreceivableamt
    FROM temp, (SELECT @n := 0) z
) y
 GROUP BY FLOOR((rownum - 1) / 5)
```

Output:

```
| CURRENT | 1-30 | 31-60 | 61-90 | >90 |
----------------------------------------
|       0 |    0 |     0 |     0 |   0 |
|   12993 |    0 |     0 |     0 |   0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bbdc0/23)** demo

Answer (score 1):

Try this sql

```
select max((CASE WHEN Agedreceivable='Current' then AgedeceivableAmt ELSE 0 END)) as Current,
max((CASE WHEN Agedreceivable='1-30' then AgedeceivableAmt ELSE 0 END)) as '1-30',
max((CASE WHEN Agedreceivable='31-60' then AgedeceivableAmt ELSE 0 END)) as '31-60',
max((CASE WHEN Agedreceivable='61-90' then AgedeceivableAmt ELSE 0 END)) as '61-90',
max((CASE WHEN Agedreceivable='>90' then AgedeceivableAmt ELSE 0 END)) as '>90'
from yourtable;
```

As you have not mentioned your entite table details i would suggest to group this records by some appropriate field, you will get the desired output otherwise you can follow @peterm's solution.

A sample Fiddle [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a053/2)

Comment: Phoenix I have tried your solution but it gives me 10 rows, as I Needed only 2 rows in output.

Comment: @Phoenix : I have attached output in EDIT